# Does NumPy have a select_dtypes like Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Objective:** to use NumPy in a similar way as Pandas with "select_dtypes".

Setting up a dataframe like the following:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2] * 3,
...                    'b': [True, False] * 3,
...                    'c': [1.0, 2.0] * 3})
>>> df
        a      b  c
0       1   True  1.0
1       2  False  2.0
2       1   True  1.0
3       2  False  2.0
4       1   True  1.0
5       2  False  2.0
```

I am looking for something like this but with NumPy:

```
>>> df.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])
   c
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  1.0
3  2.0
4  1.0
5  2.0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want to find the elements in an numpy array that are of a particular type?

Comment: Yes. I want to find an element in a numpy array that are a particular type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy arrays have elements which all have the same underlying type.
Those are essentially [C language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) arrays (and their data type has to be the same for all elements).

You can check it using `.dtype` attribute, like so:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.5, 2, 3])
print(a.dtype)
```

Would give you `np.float64`, even though two elements are inserted as `int`s

If you want to check whether a certain `float` could be an `int` (like 2 and 3 in the above example), you shouldn't do that, as floating point precision might be an issue.

If you really insist, you can use `np.isclose` to get a boolean array indicating whether each `float` element is close enough to it's floored `int` counterpart and those might be *castable* without too big loss in precision:

```
# For example above, e.g. [1.5, 2, 3]    
print(np.isclose(np.floor(a), a))
```

Would give you `[False, True, True]`, meaning second and third element could be casted. Once again, I advise you not to do so.

**EDIT:** If you have boolean numpy array casted to np.float there is no way to get it back, as you cannot differentiate between `bool` casted to `float` and `int` casted to `float` with **if** int has either `0` or `1` value.